# how to call an oracle procedure and a function inside another procedure

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a situation, where I need to do the following.

Step1: Call a procedure with the given input values and get the 2 output values.

step2: Call the function with input parameters along with one of the output value from Step1(procedure call)

Step3: Extract the output value from the return value of Step2.

Please help, how to handle this situation.

Thanks

Comment: Extract the output value... and do what with it?

Comment: The Output of Step2 is an SDO_GEOMETRY type and I need to extract just the latitude and longitude which are my expected output values

Answer (score 1):

A very basic example, with made up variable names, data types (all numbers for simplicity) and procedure/function names and signatures:

```
create or replace procedure wrapper_proc as
  -- define local variables; use appropriate data types!
  l_input_1 number;
  l_input_2 number;
  l_output_1 number;
  l_output_2 number;
  l_result number;
begin
  -- Step1: Call a procedure with the given input values and get the 2 output values.
  l_input_1 := 42;
  l_input_2 := 128;
  your_proc (l_input_1, l_input_2, l_output_1, l_output_2);
  -- l_output_1 and l_output_2 are not set by that first procedire

  -- step2: Call the function with input parameters along with one of the output value from Step1(procedure call)
  -- assuming same two original inuts, and one of the procedure outputs...
  l_result := your_func (l_input_1, l_input_2, l_output_2);

  --Step3: Extract the output value from the return value of Step2.
  -- do something unspecified with l_result
  dbms_output.put_line('Final result was: ' || l_result);
end;
/
```

Or if you want to pass the input values into that wrapper procedure:

```
create or replace procedure wrapper_proc (
  -- arguments; use appropriate data types!
  p_input_1 number,
  p_input_2 number
) as
  -- define local variables; use appropriate data types!
  l_output_1 number;
  l_output_2 number;
  l_result number;
begin
  -- Step1: Call a procedure with the given input values and get the 2 output values.
  your_proc (p_input_1, p_input_2, l_output_1, l_output_2);
  -- l_output_1 and l_output_2 are not set by that first procedire

  -- step2: Call the function with input parameters along with one of the output value from Step1(procedure call)
  -- assuming same two original inuts, and one of the procedure outputs...
  l_result := your_func (p_input_1, p_input_2, l_output_2);

  --Step3: Extract the output value from the return value of Step2.
  -- do something unspecified with l_result
  dbms_output.put_line('Final result was: ' || l_result);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you For the response. Is there a way that I can post my code here?

Comment: @Edu - you can (and usually should) include code by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58084424/edit). (And [formatting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to be readable; and saying what is wrong with it. See also: how to create a [mre].) That is, code you are having a problem with; if you've been able to solve your issue now then you shouldn't post your now-working code.